# react fluent v9 replace entire slot

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I'm trying to follow the doc here to replace an entire slot
https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/concepts-developer-customizing-components-with-slots--page#replacing-the-entire-slot

I'm getting typescript errors :

[image]
[image]

It doesn't seem like the doc has valid javascript either missing a "="

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `<TextBold24Regular />` Fluent Icon for this. Note, you can bundled the filled and regular icons. If you bundle the icon, the user will see the regular icon by default, but if they hover over the bundle, the regular icon will be replaced by the filled icon.

```
import {
  FluentProvider,
  Button,
  teamsLightTheme
} from "@fluentui/react-components";
import {
  bundleIcon,
  TextBold24Filled,
  TextBold24Regular
} from "@fluentui/react-icons";

const BoldIcon = bundleIcon(TextBold24Filled, TextBold24Regular);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FluentProvider theme={teamsLightTheme}>
      <Button icon={<BoldIcon />}>Bold</Button>
    </FluentProvider>
  );
}
```

[image]

If you still want to use a custom component, you can simply pass the JSX to the `icon` prop.

```
import {
  FluentProvider,
  Button,
  teamsLightTheme
} from "@fluentui/react-components";

const MyBoldIcon: FC = () => <b>B</b>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FluentProvider theme={teamsLightTheme}>
      <Button icon={<MyBoldIcon />}>Bold</Button>
    </FluentProvider>
  );
}
```

[image]